# Replacing matrix values with vector values

Tags: r, matrix, vector, replace

```
matrix:
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12

vector = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l")
```

How can I replace the values such that I get:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    a    e    i
[2,]    b    f    j
[3,]    c    g    k
[4,]    d    h    l
```

NB: I have used generic vectors but I will be doing this with much bigger varied data sets so I am not after something like:

```
matrix(letters[1:12],4,3)
```

Comment: `matrix[] <- vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `matrix` does only contain integers like that then you can do the following

```
mat <- matrix(sample(seq(12), 12), nrow = 4)
vec <- letters[1:12]

mat[] <- vec[mat[]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes sense for how I have shown it above.  Unfortunately it is more complicated than that for my example, but that is my fault, I am going to repost a modified version of my question.

Comment: @Aesler going from your second post, the example you provided the above solution still works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not conserving any of the original values of the matrix, the following would work

```
> matrix_name <- matrix(data = your_vector, 
                       nrow = 4,
                       ncol = 3,
                       byrow = FALSE)
```

Comment: I should have been clearer in my example.  The matrix could be non sequential numbers, so for instance the vector could have "1" as the [3,3] entry, where I would still need to replace the "1" with the first value of the vector, in this case "a".  There could also be duplicate "2"' values and hence multiple "b" values in the output matrix.

Comment: ```matrix_name <- replace(matrix_name, matrix_name == value_to_replace, replacing_value)``` Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you use a for loop with that?  That is what I initially used but the resultant for loop output only makes the last change in the sequence. ie. for (i in 1:n){replace(matrix, matrix==i, vector[i])} didn't work for me